# ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughOrderError for the has many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many-through

We are upgrading the Rails version from 5.0.6 to 5.1.4

I have the following code :

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  simple_roles
  has_many :profile_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :profile_roles
end

class ProfileRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :profile
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :profile_roles
  has_many :profile, through: :profile_roles
end
```

I got the error while doing the `Profile.first.roles` .

`ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughOrderError: Cannot have a has_many :through association 'Profile#roles' which goes through 'Profile#user_roles' before the through association is defined.`

can anyone suggest me any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your association:

In **`role.rb`**, try replacing

`has_many :profile, through: :profile_roles` with

`has_many :profiles, through: :profile_roles` in

Does this work now?

Answer (score 0):

It's not just a typo is it?

`has_many :profile, through: :profile_roles`

`:profile` should be `:profiles` I think?

Comment: This do the job @rohit?